# How to pass json as a string param with commandToExecute protectedSetting to a Powershell script?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am trying to pass a the entire placementProperties as json to a powershell script. I want to inject these into the application as an environment variable. Is this syntax correct?

PlacementProperties:
"placementProperties": {
"type": "xyz",
"ext": "png"
}

I am trying to do the following:

1. In Bicep file, for Each VMSS, I select the placement properties and send it as a parameter to the powershell script.
   *commandToExecute: 'Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path .\** -Include Test.ps1 | % { & $_.fullname -pp **${vmss.placementProperties}** }"'
2. In the Powershell script, I am trying to accept pp as a string parameter.
   `[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]`
   `[string] $pp`

Comment: could you share your bicep file please ? also are you trying to execute the powershell scrip using deployment script ?

Comment: @Thomas Apologies, I can't share the entire file. 
Yes I am trying to execute a custom powershell script.

Comment: Yes the syntax is correct and the PowerShell script will then be able to use the `pp` parameter to access the `placementProperties` object. @pagalpanda

Comment: Is it resolved with the above comment? @pagalpanda

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, providing the full* `placementProperties` *as* `JSON` *to a* `PowerShell` *script is valid syntax.*

> 1. In Bicep file, for Each VMSS, I select the placement properties and send it as a parameter to the powershell script.  *commandToExecute: 'Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path ._* -Include Test.ps1 | % { & $*.fullname -pp  **${vmss.placementProperties}**  }"':

You can select the `placementproperties` and send it as a parameter to the `powershell` script as you did.
Usually, the `commandToExecute` property is mainly used in the deployment scripts of bicep which accepts a `string` as its value. And whatever commands are required for execution will be specified in the `commandtoexecute` property.

Coming to your expression, it returns the value of the variable and the `vmss.placementProperties`, which is a `JSON` object.

> 2. In the PowerShell script, I am trying to accept pp as a string parameter.  `[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]`  `[string] $pp`:

Here the `pp` parameter's value is the `JSON` object already containing the `placement properties`. Simply inject the `placement properties` into the application as an environment variable using the `$pp` parameter in your PowerShell script.

*After detailed above, here is the sample way to inject into as an environment variable:*

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [string] $pp) 
$placementProperties = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $pp  
$env:PlacementProperties = $placementProperties
```

*Sample output:*

[image]

*Note:*  You can execute same in your bicep code or any template code to achieve the expected results.